# Changing bibliography format

Tags: natbib

I am using `natbib` for referencing. My current format is "Author, Title, Journal, Vol-pp, Year". What change should I make to bring year right after the author as in "Author, Year, Title, Journal, Vol-pp"?

Comment: What `\bibliographystyle` do you use, and what (if any) `natbib` package options?

Comment: I use this \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} and \usepackage[square,numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pondering, I don't think I'll succeed in hacking `natbib` internals. As an alternative, you could switch to [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). In the following example, I have disabled sorting, combined the `numeric-comp` citestyle with the `authoryear` bibstyle, added a label to this bibstyle and changed some other settings to mimic the `natbib` output. (This may need further tweaking.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% The following hack only works for some values of the "mergedate" option
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}{%
    }{%
    \addcomma\space
    \printtext{\printdateextra}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{Bli74}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The bibliography style you describe is fairly common in economics and finance journals. I recommend you check out the style file `jf.bst` (short for "Journal of Finance") located at http://www.ivo-welch.info/computers/bstfiles/. (Professor Welch lists many more bst files on this site.) If all else fails, you could always run the program `makebst.tex` through LaTeX to build your own `bst` file interactively. If the file `makebst.tex` isn't already on your computer system, you can obtain the latest version of this file from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/.