# New format for bibliography item

Tags: bibliographies

This is what I want : a new bibliography item format. I was looking for a matching style, but I found none, so I have to modify the default. I don't know which package to use for this.

[image]

I really don't undestand how to modify this!?
my bibliography :

the name of authors must be bold (bfserief)

the title of references must be italic

except the first line of each the reference, the indent is about 2 cm

sort by the author A,B,C-Z

the format is Authors.year.title.place/penerbitan

I use book and report class both in lyx and texmaker

I use klunum style but I get this one :
[image]

Comment: Instead of showing a picture, you should explain how exactly your desired bibliography style should differ from, say, the LaTeX standard style `plain`.

Comment: Sir, I have edit the question. I have read for http://ctan.cermin.lipi.go.id/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf .

section Author guide->interface guide and Author guide->customization, but I still don't understand to start (coding) from ?

Comment: The tricky part is swapping the position of "Year". Read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26955/changing-bibliography-format and especially Mico's answer (which does not deal with `biblatex`).

Comment: Sir, to get format like "Author.year.title.vol-pp/place" I just use the stile "klunum" I insert the result of using klunum style in my question above

Comment: @lockstep: The trick is to modify a style which has the correct position of the year ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example with biblatex. You can now manipulate this.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=numeric,labelnumber=true,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamefirst[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnameprefix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnameaffix[1]{\bfseries{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{2cm}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-2cm}%
      }%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion}\qquad\cite{markey}\qquad\cite{aristotle:physics}

\cite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```